# How or where to store FCM Background notification data in Hive in Flutter andriod?

Tags: flutter, dart, hive

I'm working on an app that needs to store notifications while it's running in the background. I've tried using put in the storage module to save the notifications, but isn`t storge when the app in background and the notifications screen is empty

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a listener for the background notification, in the listener function you need to add these values to hive.
Provide your code to assist you more.

Comment: can you help me and provide me a example code i write this 
Future<void> _messageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print('background message ${message.notification!.body}');
}

Future<void> _fierbaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}

Comment: If you need more information and if you have questions for the author of the question please use the "Add a comment" button to add a comment to the question. You can get more details and have a discussion with the author there. 

Please write the answer only when you are are certain that your answer is clear enough and contains enough information that could hel the author and future readers.